# CustomSpinnerAdaper empty on selection when items added to list after initialization adapter

Tags: android

I have problem woith my spinner.
I use it to show record retrieved from database. The problem is that after selection one of objects, it is not display as selected, and method spinner.getSelectedItem() return null.

I tried multiple combination, and I see, that the problem appears only when list is populated AFTER adapter is added to spinner.

```
initTestSpinner();
listother.add(new UserProfile("adam"));
listother.add(new UserProfile("maya"));
listother.add(new UserProfile("maria"));



private void initTestSpinner() {
    testSpinner = findViewById(R.id.second_spinner);
    adapter = new UserProfileListAdapter(this, listother);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    testSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

If I put those values before initSpinner it works fine. But any change on array list causing same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after you update the list:

```
initTestSpinner();
listother.add(new UserProfile("adam"));
listother.add(new UserProfile("maya"));
listother.add(new UserProfile("maria"));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Ok works if I run this methid on each change.  thank you